# using t.test within data.table on multiple columns

Tags: r, function, data.table, lapply

I am trying to run a t.test() on multiple columns of data within 'j' in a data.table. I've found a way that works, but isn't very elegant, and I feel like there's probably a more concise way using .SDcols, but haven't had any luck looking through here, or the data.table vignette. If this has been asked previously I apologize and please point me in the right direction.

My data.table has essentially the following format

```
DT <- data.table(name = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), 
                 y = c(rnorm(6, mean = 100, sd = 30)), 
                 z = c(rnorm(6, mean = 10, sd = 3)),
                 group = rep(c('One', 'Two'), 3))
```

When I want to run a t.test comparing the values of y in group One and group Two, it's very straightforward:

```
DT[,t.test(y~group)]
```

If I want to get an output for both y and z the following works, but is clunky and inelegant. And with my actual data, I'm trying to do this over many columns so it would be more time consuming to type out each iteration I would like to run.

```
DT[,.(t.test(y~group), t.test(z~group))]
```

In the data.table vignette, using a function over a specific subset of columns is achieved by

```
DT[,lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c('y', 'z')]
```

However replacing mean with t.test yields a one sample t.test, while I'm trying to get a two sample t.test. I've tried:

```
DT[,lapply(.SD, t.test, formula = .SDcols ~ group, data = DT), .SDcols = c('y', 'z')]
```

But this gives me a comparison between y and z, not both the comparisons of y~group and z~group.

I've tried several versions of lapply with a custom function to get the output I want, but I won't make anyone read through my walls of unsuccessful code. Needless to say I have been unable to get that to work.

**Question:**
Is there a way via lapply() or function() or a way currently unknown to me, to get t.test to run over multiple columns of data within 'j' in a data.table?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Chris

Comment: Something like this should work: `DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) t.test(x ~ group)), .SDcols = y:z]`. Here, you set up an anonymous (labmda) function that disappears after the `lapply` exits.

Comment: That worked great, I know the pvalue will get thrown to a consistent location, it's [3] on the list, so I can pull it out with DT[youranswer][3]. But do you know if there's a way to keep rownames or add an output column with the names from the ttest output? If not no worries, this was already very helpful!

Comment: If you assign the output of  the code by @lmo to `result` you can add names to it by extracting them from a dummy `t.test` with `result[,ttname:=names(t.test(1:5))]`

Comment: Thanks @DaveTurek, your suggestion provides me with a sort of summary statistics table that can be indexed to pull out the p.values, which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pull together the parts of the answer and to rearrange to put the name in the first column (if desired for nicer printing):

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(name = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), 
                 y = c(rnorm(6, mean = 100, sd = 30)), 
                 z = c(rnorm(6, mean = 10, sd = 3)),
                 group = rep(c('One', 'Two'), 3))

 result <- 
   DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x) t.test(x ~ group)), .SDcols = y:z][
   ,ttname:=names(t.test(1:5))][  # add names
   ,.(ttname,y,z)]    # put names in first column   

 result

#         ttname                       y                       z
# 1:   statistic               0.1391646               0.1295093
# 2:   parameter                3.468876                3.559917
# 3:     p.value               0.8970165               0.9039359
# 4:    conf.int     -99.61786,109.47358     -8.209637, 8.972439
# 5:    estimate       110.7286,105.8008       11.15414,10.77274
# 6:  null.value                       0                       0
# 7:      stderr                35.41031                 2.94497
# 8: alternative               two.sided               two.sided
# 9:      method Welch Two Sample t-test Welch Two Sample t-test
# 10:   data.name              x by group              x by group
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, wrapped as a function. In the accepted answer, , I didn't like that the test output was rows and the variables columns, i like it the other way around, makes it easier to read I think.

I also a added an argument for rounding, and one that default only prints the most important info, the pvalue and test statistic. the function requires purrr. the input for the group variable and the variables to test are character, so dt_test(dtx, 'varname', c('z','y'))

```
dt_ttest <- function(dtx, grp, thecols, decimals=3, small=TRUE, ...) {

    x1 <- a2[, map(.SD, ~ t.test(.x ~ get(grp))), .SDcols = thecols]

    x2 <- t(x1) %>% data.table()  
    setnames(x2, names(t.test(1:2)))
    
    x2 <- x2[, var := thecols] [, !'data.name']



    tcols <- c('p.value', 'statistic', 'stderr', 'null.value', 'parameter', 'method', 'alternative')
    x2[, (tcols) := map(.SD, unlist), .SDcols=tcols ]
    x2

    thecols2 <- keep(x2, is.numeric) %>% names()  
    x2[, (thecols2) := map(.SD, ~ round(.x, decimals)), .SDcols=thecols2 ]

    # go one level deeper to round the two list cols
    thecols3 <- c('conf.int', 'estimate')
    x2[, (thecols3) := modify_depth(.SD, 2, ~ round(.x, decimals)), .SDcols=thecols3 ]
        

    # set order
    setcolorder(x2, c('var', 'p.value', 'statistic', 'stderr', 'conf.int', 'estimate', 'parameter', 'method', 'alternative') )


    if( small) x2[, .(var, p.value, statistic)] else x2[]

}
```